# Is the t2.micro instance enough to fetch hundreds of thousands of rows?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently hosted an API on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with the free tier, I inserted 6 million rows. But I can't seem to consistently fetch data (usually around 200k at a time). Sometimes I can fetch around 100k, usually I get the error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at http://***********.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

or:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

which means it's fetching an HTML string.  I inserted one fake row and tried to fetch that and I'm able to consistently fetch it.

Am I right in assuming the free tier just isn't enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AWS Free Tier is just a billing discount. It does not affect services.

However, the use of a `t2.micro` does have an impact on network bandwidth and CPU Utilization. See: [Burstable Performance Instances - Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)

You would need to **examine the code that is producing the error** to determine exactly what is happening. For example, it might be timing-out before all the data can be downloaded due to the limited network bandwidth on such a small instance.

If you're willing to spend a few cents, you could **temporarily increase the size of the instance** (eg `t2.large` or `m5.large`) and see whether it improves the situation.

Comment: I will give this a try, I don't see any other possible solution. The logs don't mention anything about my code and like I said it does fetch the records sometimes

Comment: I tried changing it to t2.large but every time I stopped it it would automatically terminate it (why is this default behaviour?). So I turned on termination protection, then I was able to change it, but when I started the instance again it terminated. Is AWS supposed to be this bad or is it just me? lol

Comment: Ah! AWS Elastic Beanstalk uses Auto Scaling, which will automatically replace any non-responding instances to ensure that your application is running at all times. You'll need to go into the Elastic Beanstalk configuration for your app and change the Instance Type setting in there.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response! I was able to increase the size of it after being persistent, while it was on t2.large is indeed started to consistently fetch the records

Comment: And thank you! I feel like AWS could be a little more user friendly, or at least intuitive. Some things just happen with seemingly no explanation

Comment: Good to know! You could play around with the Instance Type and see which one suits your needs the most (maybe `t2.medium`?), but it would also be worth determining the cause of the problem in case increased load causes a problem again in future. I suspect it would either be CPU- or network-related. Oh, it could also be RAM, since that's quite small on a `t2.micro` too.

Comment: Yes I was going to experiment with the `t2.medium` as well. So am I supposed to disable auto-scaling? Is that in the EB menu or in the instances menu?

Comment: Also is it 100% worth removing the instance from auto scaling or is it just as good to put it on standby?

Comment: An Auto Scaling group is useful for scaling load during busy periods and for ensuring that an instance is running at all times (by replacing unhealthy instances). If you only intend to run one instance, then there is no scaling benefit. I'm not sure what you mean by "put it on standby".

Comment: I see thank you for the info, and I misspoke I meant to say "hibernate". I think ill remove it from the autocaling group

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the instance is hitting the the limit and facing any resource crunch using some basic Monitoring tool. One thing to note here is also your Instance can hit the bandwidth and be throttled by your EBS volume capabilities.

Check the performance metrics of the EBS volume as well.

After monitoring you can try and modify the size of the instance as AWS gives flexibility to modify the instance size and family.